# Python converting from a panda column to a list?

Tags: python, pandas, file, nlp

I was wondering if I have a file with the following format
[image]
and I want to put each column in a list of list since I have more than one sentences:
so the output can look like this

```
[['Learning centre of The University of Lahore is established for professional development.'], 
 ['These events, destroyed the bond between them.']]
```

and the same for the verb column. This is what I tried but it put everything in a single list not a list of lists

```
train_fn="/content/data/wiki/wiki1.train.oie"


dfE = pandas.read_csv(train_fn, sep= "\t",
                         header=0,
                         keep_default_na=False)
train_textEI = dfE['word'].tolist()
train_textEI = [' '.join(t.split()) for t in train_textEI]
train_textEI = np.array(train_textEI, dtype=object)[:, np.newaxis]
```

it outputs each word in a list

```
[['Learning'],['Center'],['of'],['The'],['University'],['of'],
 ['Lahore'],['is'],['established'],['for'],['the'],
 ['professional'],['development'],['.'],['These'],['events'],[','],
 ['destroyed'],['the'],['bond'],['between'],['them'],['.']]
```

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby('Verb')['word'].apply(lambda x: [' '.join(x)]).tolist()` ?

Comment: @jazrael but what if 2 consecutive sentences have the same verb ? I guess it would merge the 2 sentences, I tried to split based on **wordId=0** but I couldn't do it

Comment: so `df.groupby(df['word_id'].eq(0).cumsum())['word'].apply(lambda x: [' '.join(x)]).tolist()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create helper `Series` by compare `word_id` by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), `groupby` and convert to list, last convert output `Series` to list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'word_id':[0,1,2,0,1],
                   'word':['a s','ds d','sss dd','d','sd ds']})

L = df.groupby(df['word_id'].eq(0).cumsum())['word'].apply(lambda x: [' '.join(x)]).tolist()
print (L)
[['a s ds d sss dd'], ['d sd ds']]
```